# How can I inspect the Highcharts tooltip in the Chrome inspector?

Tags: html, google-chrome, highcharts

I want to be able to target the highcharts tooltip using [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) in the Chrome DOM inspector, but I need to be able to capture the class name of the tolltip to be able to do so.

When a point in a data series is hovered over in a Highcharts chart, a tooltip is displayed as you can see here:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

I am using a shared tooltip:

```
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
    },
```

However, using the inspectors 'Force element state :hover' does not work. I can't even see the tooltip appear as DOM element in the inspector at all?

How is it possible to inspect the Highcharts tooltip in the Chrome DOM inspector?

Answer (score 3):

To inspect the Highcharts tooltip in the Chrome DOM inspector you need to keep the tooltip visible. You can achieve it by wrapping the **hide** method:

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'hide', function(proceed) {});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mke7Lh3b/

Now you can easily find the tooltip **class** which is (for the point in the first series):

```
highcharts-label highcharts-tooltip         highcharts-color-0
```

`highcharts-color-0` this part is added dynamically. The number depends on which color from default Highcharts color array series have assigned.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use ctrl + F in the developper inspecteur. After you use a specific term in your tooltil press enter and you will find it easily

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).